# Ping Output: convert from .txt to excel

Tags: excel, file, text-files, ping

I have a batch file that pings 20 servers and writes the output to a .txt file.
My question is: how can I "convert" the data in my .txt to an excel document?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it in comma or tab-separated format. Excel will open that.

Alternatively, use a text processing language. A lot of people like perl for this.

Without more information as to what the output from the version of ping you have is, and what you are already writing out, we can't help you any more.

Comment: Right, I've thought of writing it in CSV stlye... but what I write to the file is the raw ms-dos output of the ping... I guess using commas would make excel put the entire ping output in one cell rather than in separate form...

Comment: Yes. You need to process the output. Good tools for doing this might be perl, gawk, or sed. If you are doing this sort of thing, you almost certainly want to get out of windows batch programming. Install cygwin, and use a shell like bash, or use the various other scripting options microsoft provides. They all have basic string processing options.